# stm32f207 ethernet interrupts problem

Tags: stm32, ethernet, interrupts, rtx-rtos

I installed RTX (rtos from Keil) and Ethernet library from STM for stm32f207 MC. I configured UDP using ethernet + LwIP as in examples from STM.

Without RTOS UDP works fine. I send and get packets without any problems, but with RTOS (RTX in my case) i can only send packets with ARP-request but can't get packets due to i have no ethernet interrupts on receiving packets (can't get ETH_DMA_FLAG_R flag). I know, that there are reciving packets because i see them in Wireshark.

So, that's how i configure Ethernet interrupts:

```
extern ETH_DMADESCTypeDef  DMARxDscrTab[ETH_RXBUFNB], DMATxDscrTab[ETH_TXBUFNB];

/* Ethernet Receive buffers  */
extern uint8_t Rx_Buff[ETH_RXBUFNB][ETH_RX_BUF_SIZE]; 

/* Ethernet Transmit buffers */
extern uint8_t Tx_Buff[ETH_TXBUFNB][ETH_TX_BUF_SIZE]; 

...
  ETH_DMATxDescChainInit(DMATxDscrTab, &Tx_Buff[0][0], ETH_TXBUFNB);

  /* Initialize Rx Descriptors list: Chain Mode  */
  ETH_DMARxDescChainInit(DMARxDscrTab, &Rx_Buff[0][0], ETH_RXBUFNB);

  /* Enable Ethernet Rx interrrupt */
    for(i=0; i<ETH_RXBUFNB; i++)
    {
      ETH_DMARxDescReceiveITConfig(&DMARxDscrTab[i], ENABLE);
    }

  for(i=0; i<ETH_TXBUFNB; i++)
  {
    ETH_DMATxDescTransmitITConfig(&DMATxDscrTab[i], ENABLE);
  }

  NVIC_EnableIRQ(ETH_IRQn);

...

void ETH_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* CANNOT ENTER HERE */
  if (ETH_GetDMAFlagStatus(ETH_DMA_FLAG_R) == SET) 
  {
    /* Give the semaphore to wakeup LwIP task */
        sys_sem_signal(&s_xRxSemaphore);
  }

  /* Clear the interrupt flags. */
  /* Clear the Eth DMA Rx IT pending bits */
  ETH_DMAClearITPendingBit(ETH_DMA_IT_R);
  ETH_DMAClearITPendingBit(ETH_DMA_IT_NIS);
}
```

So, as i said, Wireshark shows me that there are answers with ARP-requests with mac-adress, but i can't enter in interrupt to process them.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your RTOS, but with the ones I am familiar with you have to call RTOS service functions to install interrupt handlers because all interrupts are funneled through the RTOS. You're treating the interrupts as though its still a bare-metal system.

Answer (score 1):

Answer for my question is simple - i forgot about basic function for enabling DMA interrupts.

```
ETH_DMAITConfig(ETH_DMA_IT_NIS | ETH_DMA_IT_R, ENABLE);
```

where ETH_DMA_IT_NIS interrupt is necessary to include otherwise it wouldn't work for receive (and transmit if need)